# Save outlook mail automatically to a specified folder

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I would like to automatically save emails every time I receive from a particular ID (ex- 'xyz@abc.com') into a specified folder.
I can then use this file as a trigger for my script.

Can this be done? Will this need VBA or just outlook?

It would be great if the mail can be saved as a text file.

Comment: all can be done using VBA

Comment: Can you point me a link from where I can learn this?

Comment: Google your question's title and tags.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48696525/4539709

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Set Macro security low in your Outlook:**
go to File, Options, Trust Center and open Trust Center Settings, and change the Macro Settings. In Outlook 2007 and older, it’s at Tools, Macro Security.

**Open the VBA Editor:**

To put the code in a module:

1. Right click on Project1 and choose Insert > Module
2. Copy and paste the below macro into the new module.

   ```
       Public Sub SaveMsg(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
   Dim sPath As String
   Dim dtDate As Date
   Dim sName As String
   Dim enviro As String 
   enviro = CStr(Environ("USERPROFILE"))
   sName = Item.Subject
   ReplaceCharsForFileName sName, "_" 
   dtDate = Item.ReceivedTime
   sName = Format(dtDate, "yyyymmdd", vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, _
   vbUseSystem) & Format(dtDate, "-hhnnss", _
   vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, vbUseSystem) & "-" & sName & ".msg"
   ' use My Documents in older Windows.     
   sPath = enviro & "\Documents\"
   Debug.Print sPath & sName
   Item.SaveAs sPath & sName, olMsg
   End Sub
   Private Sub ReplaceCharsForFileName(sName As String, _
   sChr As String _
   )
   sName = Replace(sName, "/", sChr)
   sName = Replace(sName, "\", sChr)
   sName = Replace(sName, ":", sChr)
   sName = Replace(sName, "?", sChr)
   sName = Replace(sName, Chr(34), sChr)
   sName = Replace(sName, "<", sChr)
   sName = Replace(sName, ">", sChr)
   sName = Replace(sName, "|", sChr)
   End Sub
   ```

**This website gave me the perfect answer:**

https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/archive-outlook/save-incoming-messages-hard-drive/

Just had to copy paste their code and change the basic parameters. 
Works like gun.

Answer (score -2):

You can use a simple script, as well as rules, to auto-save attachments to folders.

```
Public Sub SaveAttachmentsToDisk(MItem As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim oAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
Dim sSaveFolder As String
   sSaveFolder = "C:\Users\DT168\Documents\outlook-attachments\"
   For Each oAttachment In MItem.Attachments
      oAttachment.SaveAsFile sSaveFolder & oAttachment.DisplayName
   Next
End Sub
```

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/3747-outlook-auto-download-save-attachments-to-folder.html

Comment: This now requires a `regedit` to work and also doesn't help with only applying to received from xyz param.