# Exporting new email to file

Tags: vba, outlook

There are a few sources from which we receive specific emails. The easiest way to categorize them is by mail title or even source email address.

We are trying to automatically save all incoming emails to file, whether it's a TXT or PDF so we can pull up a back up file when there is a problem with the network, email or whatever else is malfunctioning.

I tried to create a macro from a few similar topics;

```
Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim Inbox  As Outlook.MAPIFolder

    Set olNs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Inbox = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set Items = Inbox.Items
End Sub

Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem Then
        SaveMailAsFile Item ' call sub
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub SaveMailAsFile(ByVal Item As Object)

    Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim Inbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim SubFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim Items As Outlook.Items
    Dim ItemSubject As String
    Dim NewName As String
    Dim RevdDate As Date
    Dim Path As String
    Dim Ext As String
    Dim i As Long

    Set olNs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Inbox = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set Items = Inbox.Items.Restrict("[Subject] = 'VVAnalyze Results'")

    Path = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\Backup Reports\"
    ItemSubject = Item.Subject
    RevdDate = Item.ReceivedTime
    Ext = "txt"

    For i = Items.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set Item = Items.Item(i)

        DoEvents

        If Item.Class = olMail Then
            Debug.Print Item.Subject ' Immediate Window
            Set SubFolder = Inbox.Folders("Temp") ' <--- Update Fldr Name

            ItemSubject = Format(RevdDate, "YYYYMMDD-HHNNSS") _
                                                    & " - " & _
                                            Item.Subject & Ext

            ItemSubject = FileNameUnique(Path, ItemSubject, Ext)

            Item.SaveAs Path & ItemSubject, olTXT
            Item.Move SubFolder
        End If
    Next

    Set olNs = Nothing
    Set Inbox = Nothing
    Set SubFolder = Nothing
    Set Items = Nothing

End Sub


'// Check if the file exists
Private Function FileExists(FullName As String) As Boolean
Dim fso As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    If fso.FileExists(FullName) Then
        FileExists = True
    Else
        FileExists = False
    End If

    Exit Function
End Function

'// If the same file name exist then add (1)
Private Function FileNameUnique(Path As String, _
                               FileName As String, _
                               Ext As String) As String
Dim lngF As Long
Dim lngName As Long
    lngF = 1
    lngName = Len(FileName) - (Len(Ext) + 1)
    FileName = Left(FileName, lngName)

    Do While FileExists(Path & FileName & Chr(46) & Ext) = True
        FileName = Left(FileName, lngName) & " (" & lngF & ")"
        lngF = lngF + 1
    Loop

    FileNameUnique = FileName & Chr(46) & Ext

    Exit Function
End Function
```

While I understand that Outlook cache is available even off line some are insisting to have back up files on a physical hard drive.

I know I could manually select those files and create a copy by drag&drop but that is insufficient.

I am aware of
https://www.techhit.com/messagesave/screenshots.html. It would be difficult to have this idea accepted because GDPR blah blah blah.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this code, paste it in the ThisOutlookSession module.

To test this code sample without restarting Outlook, click in the Application_Startup procedure then click Run.

```
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
  Dim Ns As Outlook.NameSpace
  Set Ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
  Set Items = Ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
End Sub

Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
  If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem Then

  Dim sPath As String
  Dim dtDate As Date
  Dim sName As String
  Dim enviro As String

  enviro = CStr(Environ("USERPROFILE"))

  sName = Item.Subject
  ReplaceCharsForFileName sName, "_"

  dtDate = Item.ReceivedTime
  sName = Format(dtDate, "yyyymmdd", vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, _
    vbUseSystem) & Format(dtDate, "-hhnnss", _
    vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, vbUseSystem) & "-" & sName & ".msg"

' use My Documents for older Windows.
    sPath = enviro & "\Documents\"
  Debug.Print sPath & sName
  Item.SaveAs sPath & sName, olMSG

  End If

End Sub

Private Sub ReplaceCharsForFileName(sName As String, _
  sChr As String _
)
  sName = Replace(sName, "/", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "\", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, ":", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "?", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, Chr(34), sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "<", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, ">", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "|", sChr)
End Sub
```

For more information, please refer to this link:

[Save all incoming messages to the hard drive](https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/archive-outlook/save-incoming-messages-hard-drive/)

[Save outlook mail automatically to a specified folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49250227/save-outlook-mail-automatically-to-a-specified-folder)

Comment: I am trying to work on this, just doesn't seem to do anything no matter what I do and how I run the code. I managed to get it to at least give me an error with the line below; 'Item.SaveAs sPath & sName, olMSG' it gives me Run-time error '-21447286788 (800300fc)': The Operation Failed. I have modified default folder locations so I'm trying something generic first such as c:\test\ and I have no idea how to use the code more or less...I mean I get the idea of what the commands are doing but I'm quite sure problem might be just in the fact that I don't have enough knowledge in coding.

Comment: I've figure it out (had file path mistake in the code)! This is genius! So much fun Thank you so much for that! Quick question: in my understanding enviro = CStr(Environ("USERPROFILE")) let's VB know that we are working within certain user files correct? I understand I can actually input whole destination in that command. Could I also restrict this code to react to only certain group of emails? For example we receive ton of emails with the headline NEW SALE or NEW PURCHASE could I use this fact for VB to react only to those mails?